# How to export repaired ext4 filesystem to SD card without reinstall?

Tags: sd-card, debian, filesystem

So I had a Power surge the other day and the ext4 filesystem got currupted..

Now that i've repaired the (ext4) filesystem after exporting it using

```
sudo dd bs=1M if /dev/sde2 >BACKUP.IMG
```

on a live CD, and then repaired the filesystem using

```
e2fsck -fy BACKUP.IMG
```

If I mount the disk I can see the whole filesystem, it works; but how do I copy over the repaired filesystem back to my SD card? Is there any way? I don't want to reinstall the whole OS if possible, i've got a lot of configuration files that i don't want to lose and other weird stuff i forgot how I setup.

There is probably an easy way but.. I don't know (any)commands or programs, etc on Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you would copy the filesystem, repair the copy, and then want to copy it back.  If you want to make a copy first just in case repairing the filesystem causes you to lose data, go ahead -- although I am not sure how possible that outcome actually is (i.e., I don't think using fsck will cause you to lose data that wasn't essentially lost/corrupted already).  The best way to prevent data loss, of course, is to keep *regular* backups.  Once you have a problem, it may be too late.

Anyway, if you had the SD card out and mounted on another `e2fsck` equiped system (the live CD) that recognized the partition, you should have just done:

```
e2fsck -fy /dev/sde2
```

Since it apparently worked on the copy, it should work on the original.  You should/may have to ensure that the partition isn't actually mounted at the time (there's no need for it to be); `sudo umount /dev/sde2` should work for that.  Doing this will be simpler and probably less time consuming than using the repaired copy.

The first partition should be checked too; since it is vfat and not ext: `fsck.vfat /dev/sde1`.

Comment: Thank you! That did work.. I'll test booting the pi and see if it works.

Comment: Every time i plug the SD card into my PC it tells me that the drive needs to be repaired but when i press "repair" it tells me that the drive has no problems and does not need to be repaired, I think that it's the boot partition, and it's formated as FAT32. The command fsck.vfat /dev/sde1 did not do anything.. But the Pi does boot anyways..